# Как работать с большими числами в языке С++?

Tags: c++, криптография, библиотеки, числа, длинная-арифметика

скажите пожалуйста, как в С++ работать с вычислениями больших чисел для криптографии?
Мне предстоит число 45 возвести в степень в число с плавающей точкой, оно может быть в диапазоне от 1 до 256.

Привожу программный код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double a = 14.875;
    double b = 240.874;
    
    long double C = fmod(pow(45, a), 257);
    long double D = fmod(pow(45, b), 257);

    cout << "Вывод переменной C = fmod(pow(45, a), 257): " << C << endl;
    cout << "Вывод переменной D = fmod(pow(45, b), 257): " << D << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В консоле получаю вывод:

```
Вывод переменной C = fmod(pow(45, a), 257): 165
Вывод переменной D = fmod(pow(45, b), 257): nan

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Как избавиться от проблемы **num** (Not a Number) или бывает даже **inf** (infinity)?
Как я понимаю нужна какая-то библиотека для работы с большими числами, например OpenSSL или Gcrypt? Если требуется установка библиотеки, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно их устанавливать?

Comment: Первое что ответил гугл https://github.com/faheel/BigInt

Comment: Вам надо это число как-то хранить или просто вывести? Если хранить — то храните мантиссу отдельно, степень отдельно. Если вывести — то и хранить не надо :)

Comment: Можете написать  свой класс, где числа представляются в виде строки.   Арифметические действия с  ними выполняются так, как вы это сделали бы на бумаге.   Сложно, но зато есть спортивный интерес.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите вот этот набросок. Устроит?

```
void out_pow(double x, double e)
{
    double logr =  log10(x)*e;
    int ex = floor(logr);
    logr = pow(10,logr - ex);

    cout << logr << "E" << ex;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    out_pow(45,1); cout << endl;
    out_pow(45,256); cout << endl;
}
```

Вот только если надо по модулю, то тут подход иной. У вас степень точно не целочисленная? Откуда вообще такая задача? Это не [XY-проблема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY), случайно?

Но вы спросили именно о возведении в степень, так что...

P.S. Да, если насчет библиотеки — то в Boost есть multiprecision...

Comment: просто для больших чисел  результат целиком не увидеть

Comment: В коде я это указал, а вот в описании вопроса забыл, после того, как число 45 я возвёл в число с плавающей точкой, мне нужно взять это всё  по модулю 257, на выходе мне надо хранить это значение в переменной вида double.

Comment: Странно, что степень не целая... откуда такая задача? Это же не самоцель, а решение какой-то подзадачи. А вся задача в чем? Может, там как-то иначе считать надо изначально...

Comment: Мне надо реализовать алгоритм шифрования SAFER K-64, шифрование происходит в 6 раундов. И там получается 8 байт вычисляются по двум формулам (4 байта по одной формуле, 4 байта по другой), первая очень лёгкая, а вот вторая, сложная, так как большие вычисления, а именно y = (45^x)mod257, где x — входной байт, y — выходной байт.

Где x и y должны быть переменными с плавающей точкой, с большой точностью.

Comment: Разве в шифровании используются плавающие точки?... готов спорить - даже не зная алгоритма - что там целочисленные степени. А тогда это **принципиально иная** задача, и никаких больших чисел там вычислять не нужно. P.S. Почитал в википедии — степень - это входной байт, откуда же у вас дробное число?

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой возникают когда байты № 2,3,6,7 вычисляются по логарифму: логарифм по основанию 45 от x (где x — входной байт), то есть например входной байт был 105, выходной же уже будет 1,22258287, потом у нас выполняется "лавинный эффект", байты складываются и перемешиваются, и в итоге число с плавающей точкой в следующем раунде подвергается операции y = (45^x)mod257

Comment: Не так. Это не настоящий логарифм с плавающей точкой, а значение обратной функции. Почитайте внимательно, посмотрите на реализацию [здесь](https://github.com/calccrypto/Encryptions/tree/master/Encryptions), например — вы увидите, что понятие логарифм в данном контексте вы трактуете совершенно неверно... Обратите внимание в википедии — *Данные операции являются **операциями в конечном поле GF(257)***... Надеюсь, вы знаете, что в поле операция деления, например, не дает значения с плавающей точкой :) Так и тут с логарифмом...

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за то, что поправили меня, постараюсь разобраться :)